# Why do we require Node* x = new Node() instead of Node x;

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, data-structures

When I create a Node for Linked List, Stack, Queue, Trees, etc.
I have to create the ***NODE*** using
`Node* x = new Node()`
But instead, we can create the object for the Linked List, etc. using
`LinkedList x;`
for

```
class Node {
int data;
Node* next;
};

class LinkedList {
Node* head = NULL;
int size = 0;
bool push();
int pop();
};
```

Comment: Need a bit more information to make a concrete answer, but the gist of it will be `Node x;` would create anode locally scoped by the `push` function. As soon as `push` returns, `x` will go out of scope and be destroyed, and if you stored a pointer to it, that pointer now points to invalid memory. Bad things start happening shortly after that.

Comment: Because you want the LinkedList object to be destroyed as soon as the function where it is created is exited, but you don't want the Node object to be destroyed when the function where it is created is exited. You want the Node to live on in the linked list. That's the difference, it's in the *lifetime* of the objects you create. If for some reason you wanted the linked list to live on after exiting the function where it is created, then you would also create it with new.

Comment: You don't necessarily need new. You do need to make sure your node exists when you want to use it. Maybe read on the lifetime of objects.